# is there any way to disable HMR (hot modular replacement) and bundling in CRA (create -react-app)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I wanted to disable HMR in and file bundling in CRA, but somehow I can't succeed,
so I checked this question on stackoverflow for disabling HMR:[How to disable hot-loading in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66632688/how-to-disable-hot-loading-in-react)

and this question for disabling files bundling:[Disable the bundle.js bundling file Webpack creates in React using Create React App or Craco? Or at least get 'Performance' to work with source maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71441696/disable-the-bundle-js-bundling-file-webpack-creates-in-react-using-create-react)

I implemented it and worked but instead of `bundle.js`, I got `main.js` which I think it's `bundle.js` with new name.

before using craco:
[image]

after using craco:
[image]

both `main.js` and `bundle.js` sizes are equal (1.7MB of resource size)

so I wonder what's the solution for disabling file bundling and HMR in CRA?

Comment: Can I ask what your goal behind this is? Like is there a problem you're trying to solve by disabling these things?

Comment: hmr has made my code buggy during development and unbundled files is my personal preference due to some reasons @BrianThompson

Comment: For stopping HMR, it looks like you can use an environment variable when you run the dev server https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/ `FAST_REFRESH=false npm start`. For not bundling, I'd be shocked if there was a way to do this, and I can't think of a good reason to. You want the client to have to load thousands of individual JavaScript files? Your source code may not be that large, but think about all the node_modules required to make your code work

Comment: ay thanks brian, HMR solution worked lad,tnx.@BrianThompson

Comment: https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html brian read this doc, this is talking about the advantages of not bundling our code in react,@BrianThompson

Comment: code-splitting and simply not bundling are not the same thing. Code splitting *is* important for anything but a small application, but you want to split your bundle into smaller bundles, not serve every file individually. "[the bundler] can create multiple bundles". This is what the documentation is talking about - chunking or splitting using a bundler like webpack is taking your thousands of JS files and combining them into say 20 bundles instead of 1 large one. But this is still bundling.